# Is there anyway to invoke a native android function from a aspx website that is running in the web browser of the android phone?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET to create a ASP.NET web site that will run in a android mobile web browsers and like to know if there anyway to invoke a native android function from a asp.net website? or do I have to create a native listener type app that queries a database to then invoke the native function? Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using android native device capabilities using ASP.NET is difficult. Over there is the possibility of using frameworks that enable access native routines of equipment by other means. I know a framework that works this way is that using HTML5 PhoneGap (http://phonegap.com).

With this framework you can develop a wrapper to access the native routines in HTML5 and equipment through its ASP.NET page you make the call routines calling this wrapper.

First of all it is necessary that you study and analyze the framework for a better gain by using it.